# Microsoft Graph API content 401 Unauthorized

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am authenticating with client id and secret.

```
String url = String.format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token", tenantContext);
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(url, true, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
AuthenticationResult result = context.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), null).get();     
String token = result.getAccessTokenType() + " " + result.getAccessToken();
```

My application has all the permission boxes ticked and with the above token I can list users and traverse their drives and folders. I can access content from
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%s/items/%s/content which returns another URL in the Location header. However when I try to get that URL it returns 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Alternatively, the item json includes a field of the form:
`"@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{user}_{tenant}_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=...&access_token=...&prooftoken=..."`
which looks as though you ought to be able to access but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Is the other URL also on graph.microsoft.com? If not, then you need to get a new authentication token for that URL, and then use it in your download requests.

Just like you are already doing with graph.microsoft.com, but with the other server name:

```cs
AuthenticationResult result = context.acquireToken("https://onedrive-server-name", new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), null).get();
```

Comment: I tried a token for the Location url resource - `https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com` but still get 401. In `https://manage.windowsazure.com` I have added Graph, O365 Sharepoint Online and Azure AD to my app with all read permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added following permission:
Files.ReadAll or Files.ReadWriteAll
Revoke the app access and try again (https://portal.office.com/account/#apps)

However the "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl" should work out of box, maybe you disabled offline access in library settings?

Comment: I'm having no luck downloading with `ClientCredential`, `AsymmetricKeyCredential` or even with a full logged in refresh token. I get the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` but then get the 401.
Where do think downloads might be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in downloading content from users by logging in an admin user and getting a refresh token obtained from [app authentication using Azure AD](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization)

The refresh token can then be redeemed using adal4j:

```
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(url, true, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
AuthenticationResult result = context.acquireTokenByRefreshToken(refreshToken, new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), "https://graph.microsoft.com", null).get();
String token = result.getAccessTokenType() + " " + result.getAccessToken();
```

Using this access token you can get file content via:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveid}/items/{itemid}/content`

There is one vital extra step - the admin user must be added as a **site collection owner** for the user whose content you are accessing. This is described in [this blog](https://4sysops.com/archives/onedrive-for-business-part-4-access-user-files-and-ediscovery/).